# Get page width and height of a pdf

Tags: php, pdf

I searched for a while, there is a simple way to get the page dimensions of a PDF (of each page)?

I'm not clear if TCPDF or FPDF allows that.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function toPixels($value){
            //pt=point=0.352777778 mm, mm=millimeter=2.8346456675057350125948125904915 points, cm=centimeter=28.346456675057350125948125904915 points, in=inch=72 points=25.4mm
            switch(PDF_UNIT){//http://www.unitconversion.org/unit_converter/typography.html
                case "pt": return $value * 1.328352013;
                case "mm": return $value * 3.779527559;
                case "in": return $value * 96;
                case "cm": return $value * 37.795275591;
            }
            return "TEST";
        }
    
    $dimensions = [//PDF_UNIT defaults to millimeters
        "margins"   => $pdf->GetMargins(),
        "width"     => $pdf->getPageWidth(),
        "height"    => $pdf->getPageHeight(),
    ];
    $dimensions["width"] -= $dimensions["margins"]["left"] + $dimensions["margins"]["right"];
    $dimensions["height"] -= $dimensions["margins"]["top"] + $dimensions["margins"]["bottom"];
    $dimensions["width_pixels"] = toPixels($dimensions["width"]);
    $dimensions["height_pixels"] = toPixels($dimensions["height"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in charge of setting the required Page dimension while creating an pdf object. For example the Fpdf sets per default an A4 Format, you may also adapt it to your current requirements by

```
 new FPDF('P','your Unit [mm]',[width,height])
```

Those are your dimensions values which apply to every page of your pdf document.

Furhermore you may also set it for each of your page separatelly:

```
AddPage([string orientation [, mixed size [, int rotation]]]
```

And least but not last, there are alse the concept of margins, where you may draw your content.

Comment: in fpdf you must use additional tool fpdi which has an method  useTemplate, there you may tweak around, i suppose as long you do not pass any arguments, always the page default would be loaded. I haven't tested that.